# reseting/evenly distributing vertices

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices

I had a character wearing shorts, i converted these shorts to a skirt in edit mode. i made the mesh look how i wanted it, but the vertices are terrible.

is there some tool or programatic way to keep the mesh as it is but reset the vertices,  into some sort of lattice structure or evenly distributed pattern.  im happy to delete lots of vertices to do this. i just want it neat.

[image]

Comment: Suggestion.  Consider using a cylinder object which is quads, with more uniform vertex density. 3 minutes of proportional edit.  Shrinkwrap modifier to fit your existing skirt.

Comment: Some people would notice that using quads would likely be helpful for you.  Especially for organic animation.  Do you have some reason for all the apparent triangles?

Comment: i didnt make this charachter. i imported it from vroid.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "remesh" modifier on the skirt and change the voxel size until the resolution of the mesh looks like what you want. Then, apply the modifier. Attached is a link for a gif showing how it's done. https://drive.google.com/file/d/145Gv9YF8Q14uO4vAGxEKq-mhd41HgW_K/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thank you, ill have a go

Comment: Updated the answer with a video showcasing how to use the modifier, @tgmjack.

Comment: Could also try using the QuadRemesher, rather than the Voxel remesher, Might result in cleaner output.